# belvedere alternative

Tags: windows, download, file-organization

Is there an alternative for the application belvedere? Something that I could use to move files from my download folder, into their respective folders.
For example, if I download a .exe file, the software will automatically move it to the installer folder. Or if I download  a .mp3 file, it moves it to the music folder.
I'm really having difficulty using belvedere, is there any alternative that's easier to use?
For Windows OS.

Comment: How are you downloading these files?

Comment: firefox built in download manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried DropIt? http://www.lupopensuite.com/db/oth/dropit.htm
and exists a download manager that can do the move directly as it finishes to download the files with Free Download Manager